# Do I need to use the move constructor when I already have a parameter which is being taken in as an r-value reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, move, move-semantics

```
class EntityBase {
public:
    EntityBase() { std::cout << "EntityBase constructor called." << std::endl; }
    EntityBase(const std::string& name) : m_name(name) { std::cout << "EntityBase constructor string called." << std::endl; }
    EntityBase(std::string&& name) : m_name(std::move(name)) { std::cout << "EntityBase constructor string&& called." << std::endl; }
    ~EntityBase() { std::cout << "EntityBase destructor called." << std::endl; }
    private:
    std::string m_name;
};
```

In the second constructor , I am already taking in name as an rvalue reference, so do I need to use the `std::move(name)` call ?

How can I write a single constructor which can take both lvalue and rvalue references and based on the type of reference move or copy the argument ?

I expect that we don't need to use the move constructor as we have already captured the type of the argument as being an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to use the move constructor when I already have a parameter which is being taken in as an r-value reference?

Yes, because `name` has a name, when used as an expression, its value category is lvalue<sup>1</sup>. It doesn't matter it's declared type (which is a different thing from the value category of an expression) is `rvalue reference`.

> How can I write a single constructor which can take both lvalue and
> rvalue references and based on the type of reference move or copy the
> argument ?

You need a template,

```
template <typename String>
explicit EntityBase(String&& name): m_name{std::forward<String>(name)}{}
```

You may wish to add additional SFINAE checks to make sure `String` is really the type you expect it to be. Also, for single argument constructors, you should usually make the constructor `explicit`.

Alternatively, if you don't mind an extra move in the lvalue case, you can just take the string by value and then always perform a move, this will correctly handle both lvalue and rvalues.

```
explicit EntityBase(std::string name) : m_name{std::move(name)}{}
```

---

<sup>1 <sub>"Anything that has a name is lvalue" is a rule that works well enough in practice in most of the cases. For the few exceptions, refer to the canonical SO question [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)</sub></sup>